# Keep specific vnet(xx) adapter on host system for VM the same after VM shutdown/reboot

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt

Upon a shutdown and reboot the vnet(xx) adapter assigned to the VM from the VM host changes.

Is there any way to keep it a specific vnet(xx), for example vnet20 after it's shutdown for whatever reason and then rebooted.

Answer (score 0):

This is documented there (emphasis mine):

> ### [Overriding the target element](https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#overriding-the-target-element)
>
> ```
> ...
> <devices>
>   <interface type='network'>
>     <source network='default'/>
>     <target dev='vnet1'/>
>   </interface>
> </devices>
> ...
> ```
>
> If no target is specified, **certain hypervisors will automatically
> generate a name for the created tun device**. This name **can be manually
> specified**, however the **name should not start with either 'vnet',
> 'vif', 'macvtap', or 'macvlan'**, which are prefixes reserved by libvirt
> and certain hypervisors. Manually specified targets using these
> prefixes may be ignored.

So it's possible but `vnet20` couldn't be chosen to not clash. The manually defined interface will still only exist only while the VM is running.

This is probably good enough to apply network filtering rules using `ebtables`, `iptables` or `nftables`, and with probably much more efforts with other tools like route configuration or `tc` (they can only work with existing interfaces so have to be run whenever the VM is started).

To apply this on a VM named `myvm`, one can use `virsh edit myvm` (or from an authorized user on the hypervisor probably `virsh -c qemu:///system edit myvm`) to alter its settings. For example if the interface to change was defined with MAC address of 52:54:00:12:34:56 and to be used on a bridge named `virbr0`, find a block looking similar to below:

```xml
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:12:34:56'/>
      <source bridge='virbr0'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x01' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
```

and add an entry with the fixed target device name (let's use `myvmtap0`):

```xml
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:12:34:56'/>
      <source bridge='virbr0'/>
      <target dev='myvmtap0'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x01' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
```

The VM has to be stopped and started (not just restarted) for this to take effect.

This is scriptable with XML related tools, but XML looks more difficult than for example JSON. For example using `xmlstarlet`, the (one-long-line sequence of) commands below should do the same change as above, as long as it wasn't done before:

```bash
virsh -c qemu:///system dumpxml --inactive myvm | \
  xmlstarlet ed --subnode "domain/devices/interface[mac[@address='52:54:00:12:34:56']]" --type elem -n 'target' \
                --insert 'domain/devices/interface/target' --type attr -n dev -v 'myvmtap0' | \
  virsh -c qemu:///system define /dev/stdin --validate
```

Caveat: don't use blindly. Especially: it's not clearly documented if one can use a pipe (`/dev/stdin` above) instead of a file to redefine a domain (ie a VM)).

Again: the VM must then be completely stopped and then started (not simply restarted) for this to take effect.

Some credits go to:

- https://linux-blog.anracom.com/2016/02/07/kvmqemu-libvirt-virt-manager-persistent-names-for-the-virtual-network-interfaces-of-guest-systems/
- https://www.technomancy.org/xml/add-a-subnode-command-line-xmlstarlet/